# Rails update_attributes attributes in validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to get all attributes that were passed in update_attributes even they didn't change.

I have logic in my validation that if someone passed X I should skip logic.

In Rails 4.2.10 I used `original_raw_attributes` but now I am upgrading Rails.

any idea?

Comment: any reason for -1?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to access the unchanged attributes.  A workaround might be to intercept `update_attributes` and memoize the arguments, e.g.:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def update_attributes(attrs)
    @original_raw_attributes = attrs
    super
  end
  before_validation do
    pp @original_raw_attributes if @original_raw_attributes
  end
end
```

And an example of using it to display attributes that aren't being updated:

```
>> User.last.name
=> "tomc"
>> User.last.update_attributes name: "tomc"
{:name=>"tomc"}
```

You'd probably want to put that in a `Concern`, but you get the idea.